# How to pass variable value to a flag in AZCopy?

Tags: sql-server

I have a Powershell script executing code below. Variable values are being passed to source and destination fine, however, the one sent to --include-pattern is not working.
Any idea on is it possible to have a variable sent to a flag at all or how to configure it?

Thanks.

```
$path = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input backup copy destination'
$sas = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your sas file name'             
$Pattern = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the Backup pattern name'   
$content = Get-Content $sas

G:\Installations\azcopy_windows_amd64_10.16.0\azcopy.exe sync $content $path --delete-destination=true --include-pattern=$Pattern
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your `--include-pattern` needs to be "quoted". This can be particularly important given that you are taking in arbitrary inputs.

Also keep in mind that when using quotes in PowerShell, 'single quotes' will behave differently than "double quotes", particularly when it comes to [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60329476/1948808).

Depending on how much you've simplified your example from your original code, you could *also* be running into an interpolation issue. For any dynamically-constructed commands, be careful that you may have to ensure you're using the right quotes in the right places, and that you are escaping `$variables` correctly when they are mid-string.

This version should work, even when it is embedded in a larger, more complex, more dynamic script:

```
azcopy.exe sync ${content} ${path} --delete-destination=true --include-pattern="${Pattern}"
```

Comment: Thanks AMtwo for your help.